# Where is "Shared with me" in the new google drive layout?

Tags: google-drive

Where is "Shared with me" in the new google drive layout? I can't seem to find documents the were shared with me in the new google drive interface. Once I switch back to the old interface I can see those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Share with me** is changed to **Incoming** in the new Google Drive design.

You can find it on the menu, at the top left corner you'll find three horizontal lines, press it, and you'll see the menu along with Incoming option.

Comment: Thank you. Totally missed that. I was not expecting it to be called "Incoming".